# The Telegram bot created with Botman does not communicate with Telegram

Tags: laravel, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I created a Telegram Bot using [Botman](https://botman.io/2.0/welcome) but I can't get it to communicate with the Telegram bees and then interact with it.

I state that I configured the bot project following the Botman documentation but after numerous attempts to set the webhook and the relative routes that the bot had to use I could not make it work properly.

I attach it under the BotManController source.

The bot was installed in a subfolder of my hosting space and I tried to set the bot webhook by sending a post request of this type:

> https://api.telegram.org/bot897***************/setWebHook?url=https://miodominio.ovh/nomebot/botman

The request is then successful but the bot is not connected to the Telegram bees and therefore it is not possible to interact with him via Telegram.

```
/* metodi nel BotManController.php */


public function handle()
{
    $botman = app('botman');

    $botman->listen();
}

public function tinker()
{
    return view('tinker');
}

public function startConversation(BotMan $bot)
{
    $bot->startConversation(new ExampleConversation());
}
```

P.s. In the comment the link to the routes / botman.php and routes / web.php files

Comment: Link to the source of the routes / botman.php files and the routes / web.php file:  pastebin.com/raw/wCp7GDwg e pastebin.com/raw/XEa2UXc2

Comment: What's the result of Telegram server ? do you have valid SSL? what error you get? please more specific .